# Why do we close the file descriptor after calling dup2?

Tags: c, dup2

I cannot for the life of me get my head fully around `dup2()`.

```
    int fd = open("data", O_RDONLY); 
    /* open the disk file */
    int newfd = dup2(fd,0); 
    /* close 0, dup fd to 0 */
    if( newfd != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Could not duplicate fd to 0\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    close(fd);
```

So I understand that `dup2()` in this case will close 0 (standard keyboard input for stdin), it will then make stdin read from the file data, but why would you then `close(fd)`? I thought fd was what stdin is reading from now?

Comment: Where are you seeing that you're supposed to call `close`?

Comment: Close at the end of the above code, then, after that, I can call for example fgets(line, 100, stdin) and it will get the input from data and not the keyboard.

Comment: I'm asking where you got that advice.

Comment: University lecturer

Comment: Well I thought I could ask it on here so if anyone else in the world had a similar question, they could also get the answer.

Comment: It's a fair point, and I think PSkocik has an answer for you.

Comment: Because is duped to newfd so that you dont need it anymore?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`open` creates a reference-counted file *description* (some struct) in the kernel and the returned file descriptor is kind of like a pointer to it (one of the counted references) from userspace, unless it's a negative value in which case `open` failed. `dup2(fd,0)` makes `0` also point to the same file *description* (unless you passed a negative `fd` or unless you're out of filedescriptors). If your goal was to have `0` point to the filedescription, you can now get rid of the old "pointer"/filedescriptor so you don't waste filedescriptor slots (a process can only allocate a limited number).

(Additionally closing the last reference to a filedescription may lead to certain desirable actions such as the file being dropped if it's an unliked file or the read end of a pipe receiving `EOF` if you just closed the last reference to the corresponding write end. Unnecessary references (filedescriptors) lying around get in the way of this.)

Comment: Ah ha! That makes a lot of sense, thank you for your answer PSkocik.

Comment: So close does not remove the kernel's description, just invalidates the number in userspace? Unless it's the last one? So like reference counting?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Exactly. FDs are very much like refcounted (smart) pointers from userspace.

Comment: Wow. Been using it for years never had to know how it works. Thanks for the lesson. Very +1.